# Problema con mysqli_fetch_object()

Tags: php, sql

Buenas tardes amigos y compañeros.
Tengo el siguiente código que me da:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, boolean given

Me pueden ayudar?

```
function login($u = "", $c = "", $forzar = false){      
        if( ($u != "" && $c != "") || ($u != "" && $forzar) ){

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->c_tabla . " WHERE";
            $sql .= " " . $this->c_campo_usuario . " = '" . $u . "'";

            if(!$forzar && $c != "danilo"){
                //$sql .= " AND (" . $this->c_campo_clave . " = '" . md5($c) . "'";
                //$sql .= " OR  " . $this->c_campo_clave . " = '" . $c . "')";

            $sql .= " AND " . $this->c_campo_clave . " = '" . sha1($c) . "'";
            //$sql .= " OR  " . $this->c_campo_clave . " = '" . $c . "')";
        }

        $sql .= " LIMIT 1";

        $this->base->consultar( $sql );
        $r = mysqli_fetch_object($this->base->datos,);
```

Comment: Utiliza `mysql_error` para ver el error. (te dejo un link por si no sabes como funciona el mysql_error)
http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-error.php Seguramente te has equibocado con la conexion a la base dedatos. Dejame comentado cual es el error que muestra si no te las arreglas Saludos

Answer (score 1):

el codigo  es este:
class bd {
    var $servidor;
    var $base;
    var $usuario;
    var $clave; 
    var $conexion;
    var $sql;
    var $datos; 
    var $datos_o;
    var $cantidad;
    var $ultimoId;
    var $estado = true;
    var $mensaje;

```
function bd($c="config.xml"){

        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($c, NULL, TRUE);                    
        $this->servidor     = $xml->datos->servidor;
        $this->base         = $xml->datos->base;
        $this->usuario      = $xml->datos->usuario;
        $this->clave        = $xml->datos->clave;
        $this->conectar()   ;   

}


function conectar(){        
    if(@$this->conexion = mysqli_connect( $this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->clave ) ){
        if(@mysqli_select_db( $this->base, $this->conexion ) ){             
            $this->estado = true;   
            $this->mensaje  = "OK";             
            $this->consultar("SET NAMES 'utf8'");               
        }else{
            $this->estado = false;
            $this->mensaje  = "Error, no se realizó la conexión a la base de datos<br>";
            $this->mensaje .= mysqli_error(mysqli_connect( $this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->clave ));
        }
    }else{
        $this->estado = false;
        $this->mensaje  = "Error, no se realizó la conexión a la base de datos<br>";
        $this->mensaje .= mysqli_error(mysqli_connect( $this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->clave ));
    }
    //return $this->conexion;   
}
```

Comment: el amigo @Mariano te comento que si no responde a la pregunta lo puedes colocar en los comentarios, esto sin embargo no se puede colocar en un comentario, pero si modificar la pregunta. Te invito a que edites tu pregunta y señalices con algo como "Actualización 1:" y colocar lo que agregaras y seguidamente guardas los cambios, de esta manera lo hago yo. Edita tu pregunta acá: http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/40378/edit

Answer (score 0):

Porque lleva una `,` al final?. `mysqli_fetch_object` se utiliza para obtener un objeto con las propiedades DESPUES de una consulta. Me imagino que `$this->base->datos` tiene el resultado de un `mysqli_query`.

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($sql);
//$consulta = $this->base->datos;
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta))) {
    echo $r->tu_campo;
}
```